# Plugged in but not Charging

Tags: battery

My HP laptop , shows that it is plugged in but not charging , When ever I take out my adapter it simply shuts down . It Always stays at 0% , its has been this way for years and im considering to buy a new battery . Please help if you know the answer
.

Comment: Replace the battery.

Comment: Hello Mokubai , I dont think that my battery is dead , as it happend suddenly .

Comment: It can happen suddenly. Cells do fail.

Comment: If you have additional information or evidence why you believe something you can [edit] your question.